# Combining every 15 rows into one across numerous rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, combine

I have data spreading out in 45000 rows (single column).
I need to combine every 15 rows into single row.
So in the end I need to have 3000 rows with combined data from every 15 rows.

from:

```
row 1 
row 2
row 3
row 4
etc...
```

into:

```
row 1  (rows 1-15)
row 2  (rows 16-30)
row 3  (rows 31-45)
row 4  (rows 46-60)
etc...
```

I know how to combine 15 rows into one, but don't know how to create module to repeat this across all 45000 rows.

So far I used CONCATENATE function to combine multiple rows (15) into a single one. However there are just too many rows (45000) and I need to find the way to do this automatically across all the rows. So I think I need to create a macro using VBA.

The data in the rows are combination of numbers and strings, here is example of first few rows:

```
20181102-112745254375,$IIGLL,4342.3344,N,01548.0639,E,102745.00,A,A*7E
20181102-112745306452,$IIHDG,264.0,,,3.90,E*18
20181102-112745342864,$IIHDT,267.9,T*28
20181102-112745385244,$IIHDM,264.0,M*22
```

Comment: Would you care to show us what have you tried? Is this a Formula question or a VBA question? How do you want to merge/concatenate? What's the data is it all strings, or numbers and dates?

Comment: Since you have used CONCATENATE, you can pass INDEX manipulated with ROW function * 15 +1, +2, +3 up to +15  to it, to get every 15 rows concatenated into one and in contagious way.

Comment: Thx. I understand what you mean don't know how to use that functions. Can you please specify the formula I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I best understand, I suggest a solution that still uses CONCATENATE but in combination with INDEX & ROW to manipulate the data.

The sample data is in Column A starting with A1 and below. If this starting cell is different, then a slight manipulation is required in the formula.

The formula is longish, to somewhat shorten it I have used a Name in Name Manager called as Name1.

Go to Name Manager and create a new name called Name1 with formula as

```
=(ROW()-1)*15
```

[image]

Now in B1 put the following formula

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX($A:$A,Name1+1),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+2),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+3),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+4),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+5),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+6),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+7),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+8),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+9),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+10),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+11),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+12),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+13),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+14),INDEX($A:$A,Name1+15))
```

and drag it down up to the intended rows.

Now every 15 rows from column A starting 1st cell shall be concatenated into a single cell stacked one below the other in Cell B1, B2 and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well. I just had to replace "," for ";" in formula because of different region I guess.

Comment: Yes, List Separator for your region in Windows is likely to be ; instead of ,